# Can Prince Philip's will be unsealed before 2111?

Tags: united-kingdom, wills, appeal, monarchy

His will was sealed for 90 years when he died, and the Guardian's appeal failed.

Can someone else do a different appeal and get it unsealed?

Is there any way it will be unsealed before the 90 years is up?

Comment: I removed the last two sentences. Whether it's fair is a matter of opinion, and whether it could have information about Diana is a separate question.

Comment: Please don't edit my questions.

Comment: @StandingThereIsYou [Editing content is a part of the Stack Exchange system](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/editing). Your question contained two sub-questions which are off-topic on this website. This is a website about questions about law. We don't host questions about fairness and we don't host questions asking for wild speculation. The alternative to deleting those sub-questions would be to close the whole question as off-topic.

Comment: Fairness questions repeatedly get closed for being opinion based or edited to be on topic. This one was edited. We also don't deal in speculation, which was the 2nd subquestion. We don't deal in "Why is the law written the way it is?" either - the answer to that is "Because the lawmaker said it is!" in most cases or "Because common law" in the others.